# Python, Scraping Data from javascript website

Tags: javascript, python, web, screen-scraping

So, i am kinda of a new python programmer, if i can call myself like that, and i am trying to learn through the "picking new projects" procedure.
What i want to do now is :

enter a website that gives live score results as http://www.livescore.com for example.
somehow scrape all the teams that playing against each other and manipulate those data. 
Then i want to build an app that takes those data, arrange them nicely in a table format (let's say) and then update it every time a team scores a goal (possibly through scrapping again ? i don't know..). So i want to project them as my own data.

As i am new to python, i don't even know if that's possible to be done.
If so, can you help me ? Point me to some directions maybe, point me specific chapters of python to read, specific modules etc etc ?

I really need any help i can get because i am really lost on the matter.
I don't know where to begin with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use the site that provides API. Find such website and read instructions. The base use of any API is interacting with website by different web requests. In python it can be done using `requests` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For web scraping i would recommand using regular requests library of python + the **BeautifulSoup** library for parsing HTML. This way you can have a look at the content of the website.

The problem starts with dynamically added data, which is probably the case for you. the actual live data is probably coming from XHR requests the site is making to the server, so there lies the data you are really interested in.
In order to get the data you can try looking at those XHR requests and maybe try to mimic them.

Another platform from extracting data from sites is the **Selenium** project. Its more of an automated web browser, which gives you the access to all the data , even the dynamically loaded ones.